# Attempt to print string return results in random characters (long read)

Tags: c++, function, reference, return

This might take a bit to explain.

I'm making a text-based game for a programming class. I'm attempting to describe the environment the player is currently in, based on their input.
First step:

```
if (playerChoice == 3) { //If they choose option 3, run the describe environment function
    bool restart = CheckSurroundings(PlayerCharacter, ItemList, Map);
}
```

Next step:

```
static bool CheckSurroundings(Player &PlayerCharacter, vector <Item> &ItemList, vector<Area> &Map) {
    cout << Map[PlayerCharacter.Position()].GetDescription() << endl;
    //cut unimportant stuff out
    return false;
}
```

What's above currently outputs a smiley face on my desktop computer, and printed an entirely different character when ran on my laptop.

"Map" is a vector of Area objects:

```
int mapSize = 17;
vector <Area> Map (mapSize);
SetupMapID(Map, itemList, mapSize);
```

The inclusion of the function SetupMapID is important. It's where I "set up" the map vector by giving all of the area objects inside the vector their name, description, and additional attributes. This is a preview of what it looks like:

```
static void SetupMapID(vector<Area> &Map, vector <Item> ItemList, int mapSize) {
    Map[0].Name("The Mall Entrance Hallway");
    Map[0].Description("The entrance to the mall has been blockaded with various benches, trash cans empty vending machines, and the occaisonal wood plank. This won't keep the zombies out for long.");
    Map[0].Accessible(true);
}
```

Here is the actual area class header file (or, some of it, with what's unimportant cut out)

```
class Area {
    private:
        std::string areaName;
        std::string areaDescription;

    public:
        std::string Name() { //GetName
            return areaName;
        }
        void Name(std::string newName) { //SetName
            areaName = newName;
        }

        //Area Description
        std::string Description() { //GetDescription
            return areaDescription;
        }
        void Description(std::string newDesc) { //SetDescription
            areaDescription = newDesc;
        }
};
```

EDIT: In case someone asks, I DO have a constructor set up, where description is given the string of "A".

Now that all of the context that should need to be given has been given, I can jump back up to the cout statement from above:

```
cout << Map[PlayerCharacter.Position()].Description() << endl;
```

Map, is as you saw, a vector of Area objects, and I'm looking to grab the Area object that the Player is currently in, which can be retrieved with PlayerCharacter.Position() (this returns 0 - 15). So "Map[PlayerCharacter.Position()]" gets that Area object. Then, after that. The function Description(), with no params, returns the object's description string. Nothing super complicated, but for reasons unknown to me, instead of returning the string it ought to be returning ("The entrance to the mall has been blockaded..."), it returns a random ASCII character (I think ASCII?). On my desktop computer, it always returns a smiley face.

This is where I'm stuck. Why is it returning a smiley face? The Name() function functions as intended (returns the area's "name" as a string), and everything associated with THAT is called stylistically the exact same.

Please help! I can work around it by just creating an array of strings and throwing the Area's # at it, but I would most prefer avoiding that.

I'm wondering if the problem has something to do with running out of space? My instructor thought it might have something to do with using reference variables, but I have absolutely no clue why Name() works but Description() doesn't.

Comment: This might be the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hmm, I suppose that is kind of my post. I feel bad for writing it, but I honestly have NO CLUE how to fix my problem. I spent 2 hours trying to debug the problem and got no solution.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I'd bet a bounds issue. What happens if you replace `Map[PlayerCharacter.Position()]` with `Map.at(PlayerCharacter.Position())`

Comment: I don't see you ever resizing your vector, so it would appear all of your accesses are out of bounds.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I was thinking it might be a bounds problem as well, but I've replaced it as you suggested and I'm still getting the evil smiling face looking back at me :(

Comment: @RetiredNinja I instantiated the vector with 17 empty Area objects when I created the Map vector, look above at the post

Comment: @MFisherKDX, does `operator[]` and `at()` differ here?

Comment: @codekaizer operator [ ] doesn't check if you're accessing an array out of bounds, at() will check. That's one of the advantages of the std::Vector class

Comment: @codekaizer, no it doesn't slove the problem. but if there's a bounds issue, it should let you know. then you'd have to figure out why and fix your bug. ;)

Comment: Your example is incomplete. Nobody is going to try and piece together your little snippets into a complete program, and if they do it's very doubtful it will be the same as yours. Shrink your example into something you can post here in one code block demonstrating the problem. Like this: https://ideone.com/K9Ert7  If you find as you shrink your example that the problem goes away then you've narrowed down what it is. Use that knowledge to construct your example for here, or perhaps you'll see how to fix the problem yourself. Learning to debug your programs is an important skill to learn.

Comment: @codekaizer Because I already instantiated Map as being 17 big. Just didn't bother creating individual Area objects for the vector. Maybe that's my Lua background.

Comment: @codekaizer I can move around (in the game) and each Area's name is properly displayed, and other variables attached to the Area object are being used as intended, only Description() isn't working.

Comment: Why you are only setting description in first element of vector i.e. Map[0]

Comment: @Kapil I do for every element I used, I just cut it out so the post isn't as long. They all follow the format you see.

Comment: @codekaizer Correct; for each Area object in the vector, that works. I've already playtested my game a bit. Everything BUT description works exactly as intended.

Comment: Make us something that's minimal, complete, and will actually run. You're already like 75% of the way there. You don't show us the other classes(I think only Player is what we care about, Item doesn't seem pertinent), you don't show us the constructor for Area, include those, just do a single case, not all 17, etc. Lots of the time doing that finds the problem. What system are you running on? What's the compiler?

Comment: @mock_blatt What's shown is what's necessary regarding the problem. The only thing related to the Player class is .Position(), which I already said returns a value between 0 and 15 (and nothing else - I've tested). I'm on W7, and running on Visual Studio 2017 or 2018, whichever's the newest version is.

Comment: @Logan, nobody here has been able to reproduce the problem in our heads with the code you've given. So if you want help, you will have to provide the rest of the code so we can reproduce the problem on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 5 minutes assembling your snippets (via copying and pasting) into an actual compilable and executable code snippet.

If I compile the below with gcc on Linux, I get the following output (copied and pasted straight from the console window):

The Mall Entrance Hallway
The entrance to the mall has been blockaded with various benches, trash cans empty vending machines, and the occaisonal wood plank. This won't keep the zombies out for long.

So it works, code is below. The broken part is not in what you showed us OR there's an issue with your compiler or environment, which I think is extremely unlikely but now you can just copy the below and test for yourself. I made some extremely simplifying assumptions on the parts you didn't show us, so you're going to have to share those or figure out why your outcome is different. My first suggestion would be to put your actual Player class and Position() function in place of mine. I wonder if perhaps your call to Position modifies the state of the internal member somehow so the first call (for Name) works but the second call doesn't. Just a thought.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Area {
    private:
        std::string areaName;
        std::string areaDescription;

    public:
        std::string Name() { //GetName
            return areaName;
        }
        void Name(std::string newName) { //SetName
            areaName = newName;
        }

        //Area Description
        std::string Description() { //GetDescription
            return areaDescription;
        }
        void Description(std::string newDesc) { //SetDescription
            areaDescription = newDesc;
        }
};

static void SetupMapID(vector<Area> &Map, int mapSize) {
    Map[0].Name("The Mall Entrance Hallway");
    Map[0].Description("The entrance to the mall has been blockaded with various benches, trash cans empty vending machines, and the occaisonal wood plank. This won't keep the zombies out for long.");
}

class Player {    
public:
    int Position() {
        return 0;
    }    
};


int main()
{    
    int mapSize = 17;
    vector <Area> Map (mapSize);
    SetupMapID(Map, mapSize);

    Player PlayerCharacter;
    cout << Map[PlayerCharacter.Position()].Name() << endl;
    cout << Map[PlayerCharacter.Position()].Description() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```